# How to get the Valefor Hat MapleStory as a Night Walker?

Tags: maplestory

I am a Night Walker level 13 in [MapleStory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapleStory). Can I get the hat?

If I can, what quests do I need to do? And please explain in detail, because I just started playing MapleStory.

I also know that as a Night Walker it's possible to get the hat without scissors of karma, but I don't know how.

Comment: Possibly *[How do I get the Valefor Hat?](http://www.sleepywood.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1630123)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Hidden Street](http://global.hidden-street.net/quest/job/catch-valefor), the quest you need to get the hat (*Catch Valefor!*) is a Adventurer Thief-only quest, meaning no Night Walkers. However, these are the steps you need to complete the quest:

> 1. Talk to Dark Lord in Kerning City: Thieves' Hideout.
> 2. Go to Swamp Region: Dangerous Croco and talk to Demon's Doorway.
> 3. You will be teleported to Mini Dungeon: Valefor Strolling Path.
> 4. Go to the top of the map and go through the portal to Mini Dungeon: Valefor Hiding Place.
> 5. Defeat Valefor.
> 6. Return to Dark Lord once you have completed the task.

Additionally, the quest is a level 18 - 40 quest, and you need to have the [*Shumi, the Coin Maniac*](http://global.hidden-street.net/quest/job/shumi-the-coin-maniac) quest completed.

Comment: hmmm but my friend has one and he did not use scissors of karma to get it and he made a video of his night lord fighting the mule thing, but for some reason he wont tell me how to get it.

Comment: Night Lords are allowed to complete the quest, as they are an Adventurer Thief. Also, remember the possibility that your friend *could be* lying to you. ;)